# xml transformation via xsl (msxsl)

Tags: xml, xslt, msxsl

I need to convert a xml-file to a csv-file. Therefore I'm using msxsl. The xml-file looks like this:

```
(...)
<Test>
  <Field1>Blabla</Field1>
  <Values>
    <Year>2012</Year> 
    <Value>12</Value>
  </Values>
  <Values>
    <Year>2013</Year> 
    <Value>1234</Value>
  </Values>
  <Field2>abc</Field2>
</Test>

<Test>
  <Field1>Blubblub</Field1>
  <Field2>def</Field2>
</Test>
(...)
```

Which means: There are data sets "Test" with several nodes "Values", and others without any.

I tried to solve this with for-each:

```
(...)
<xsl:for-each select="Test">
(...)
<xsl:for-each select="Values">
(...)
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
(...)
```

This works (in a way), but the number of colums does not match between the data sets. I need to have in every data set the maximum number of colums for every node in the whole file.

In the end one should be able to open the csv-file with excel. Therefore each column need to contain the same data... is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Edit: In this case the expected csv-output would look like this:

```
Blabla;2012;12;2013;1234;abc
Blubblub;;;;;def
```

... and NOT:

```
Blabla;2012;12;2013;1234;abc
Blubblub;def
```

Comment: Perhaps this would be clearer if we could see the expected output of transforming the example.

Comment: excel will open an xml file, might still need a transform, but it could be a less painful one.

Comment: I've added the expected csv-output. Excel cannot open these xml-files. We do not know, why - using msxsl is the alternative solution...

Comment: Can one assume that every `<Values>` element contains two values? And that the two 'fields' are repeated in every  `<Test>` element?

Comment: Yes, every <Values> element contains the same two values and also the two fields are repeated in every <Test> element. Additionally we know, that <Values> appears 0 to 10 times in a <Test> element.

Answer (score 0):

Given your expected CSV output (actually SSV, semicolon-separated-values, it seems), I don't think you want an inner `for-each` at all.  I would do it more along the lines of:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Test">
    <xsl:value-of select="Field1"/>
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Values[1]/Year"/>
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Values[1]/Value"/>
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Values[2]/Year"/>
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Values[2]/Value"/>
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>

    <!-- etc, up to the final... -->

    <xsl:value-of select="Field2"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This gives you a fixed number of fields, with empty values where no node exists.

Comment: You are assuming that the maximum number of `<Values>` elements in a `<Test>` is known and can be hard-coded.

Comment: Yes, I am, because he needs to have "Field2" in a constant CSV column, and that will only happen if a maximum is known ahead of time.

Comment: My guess is that "Field2" needs to be the **last** column - not necessarily constant for all transformed documents. But that's for the OP to clarify.

Comment: Actually we do know that <Values> can appear at most 10 times. So this would be the solution. Many thanks!